# Как получить заголовок страницы или поста по URL в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

У меня есть URL страницы, по нему мне нужно получить заголовок этой страницы.
Например я нахожусь на странице Контакты

```
http://localhost/sitename/kontakty/
```

и в каком-то месте мне нужно сделать ссылку на страницу, URL которой мне известен

```
http://localhost/sitename/katalog/rotor/
```

Нужно сервером отрендерить

```
<a href="http://localhost/sitename/katalog/rotor/">Роторный двигатель Mazda</a>
```

Comment: Читайте документацию к вордпрессу на предмет основного цикла, а также о функциях, например про the_title().

Comment: Уже нашел решение, сейчас напишу ответ

Answer (score 1):

Можно получить так:

```
$page = get_page_by_path( 'parent-page/sub-page' );
$post_title = get_the_title( $page );
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php
$json_prev_category = get_home_url() . '/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/?slug=' . 'rotor';
$info = file_get_contents($json_prev_category);
$info = json_decode($info, true);
?>
<a href="<?php echo $info[0]['link']; ?>"><?php echo $info[0]['title']['rendered']; ?></a>
```

Comment: Это ужасный способ. Левой ногой правое ухо. Вы грузите весь сайт снова, со всеми плагинами. Зачем? Вам SeVlad дал правильный ответ.